# Joomla create Router.php for images url

Tags: php, joomla, router

I tried to create router.php to set SEF url form img src.
To display it in src i use as fallowing:

```
<?php echo JRoute::_(JURI::root().'components/com_mycomponent/myimg/mythumb/'.$thumb->id.'.'.jpg); ?>
```

To write a router i use instruction from Joomla Wiki but without results :/

I just donk know how to write a router for images src ??

I hope somebody could help me.

My code of router.php

```
function [componentname]BuildRoute(&$query)
{
       $segments = array();
       if (isset($query['catid']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['catid'];
                unset($query['catid']);
       };
       if (isset($query['id']))
       {
                $segments[] = $query['id'];
                unset($query['id']);
       };
       unset($query['view']);
       return $segments;
}
function [componentname]ParseRoute($segments)
{
       $vars = array();
       $app = JFactory::getApplication();
       $menu = $app->getMenu();
       $item = $menu->getActive();
       // Count segments
       $count = count($segments);
       // Handle View and Identifier
       switch ($item->query['view'])
       {
               case 'categories':
                       if ($count == 1)
                       {
                               $vars['view'] = 'category';
                       }
                       if ($count == 2)
                       {
                               $vars['view'] = 'article';
                       }
                       $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
                       $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
                       break;
               case 'category':
                       $id = explode(':', $segments[$count-1]);
                       $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0];
                       $vars['view'] = 'article';
                       break;
       }
       return $vars;
}
```

I use this code above byt i change component name and i change catid and id on my folders for example muimg and mythumb

Sorry if this question is dumm but i m very new in joomla development

Comment: What do you mean by without results? Is it blank? What are you getting and what are you expecting? Also it's hard to tell anything without code.

Comment: Images don't have categories or ids so you wouldn't use them ... what exactly are tyou trying to achieve? Are you trying to create an image document type?  Since images are not in the database what would you be rewriting the names to be? I'm just not seeing why you need to do anything beside add the JURI::route() for the base path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure what exactly you're trying to achieve but your first code snippet is incorrect and will result in an error. So you need to change this:

```
(JURI::root().'components/com_mycomponent/myimg/mythumb/'.$thumb->id.'.'.jpg);
```

to this:

```
(JUri::root().'components/com_mycomponent/myimg/mythumb/'.$thumb->id.'.jpg');
```